# How to download "ResourceFunction" packages onto a notebook, so I can place it in a USB and access it on a different computer

Tags: packages, paclets, resourcefunction, caching

So I want to use "ResourceFunction" commands, but that requires internet, as it needs to retrieve it from the wolfram cloud. However, I want to access a number of them (such as, ResourceFunction["TangentLine"], ResourceFunction["StationaryPoints"] etc.) on a different computer at work (which doesn't have access to internet). Is there a way I can retrieve the commands from the Wolfram cloud on my laptop at home, and copy that notebook onto a USB and plug that USB into the work computer and get the commands to work there, without internet?

Please assist.
Thanks :)

Comment: Can I use something such as DefineResourceFunction ?

Comment: Why can't you download each of the resource functions you want since the source notebook is there, put them on a flash or burn to CD and then just import them as needed in your session without use of ResourceFunction?

Comment: @Moo thats what I am asking, I don't know how to do that, can you please tell me how to download it. Previously I just defined the function and it got a result from the cloud, and then I turned my internet off and the function still worked for other equations. So I put it into a USB and took it to work. However once I got there, and plugged it in, it didn't work, as it says couldn't retrieve from cloud . which I'm guessing it due to not being able to access the internet.

Comment: Go to this site: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository, find whichever resources you want, and then look at the top right of the page - to code is there for downloading. For example, look at the top right of https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/LocalMinima, see "Source Notebook" - that is the actual code. Clear?

Comment: You might be interested in [`ResourceFunction["PacletizeResourceFunction"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PacletizeResourceFunction), which will attempt to automatically bundle resource functions into a paclet. If you specify a file path, the paclet will be saved to that path instead of being automatically installed, allowing you to copy it to another computer.

Comment: I have seen some ResourceFuntions that don't have a ResourceNotebook link at the top right corner. When that happened I let Wolfram Research know via the Feedback link at the bottom and they fix it the next day.

Comment: @LukasLang how do I specify a file path? Bit lost ://

Comment: @Moo got that thanks!

Comment: I found a function ResourceFunction["PersistResourceFunction"] that works, but I am confused as to if it saves it to the notebook, or my laptop?

Comment: @blacke23 See the examples on the documentation page of `PacletizeResourceFunction` - in particular, the second to last example in the "Scope" section shows how to package two resource functions into a paclet file. Instead of doing the `PacletInstall` step on the same computer, you can just copy the file and do that step on any other machine

Comment: @LukasLang Great! I got them as *function*.paclet files on my desktop. Ill copy them into my USB and once I plug it into my work computer, how do I call upon them in the notebook?

Comment: @blacke23 You should be able to just call `PacletInstall["path/to/file.paclet"]` once to install it, and then use the functions like normal functions (as shown in the documentation). Let me know if there are issues with the pacletized functions, then I can try to fix `PacletizeResourceFunction` if possible

Comment: @LukasLang Thank you so much. It works perfectly so far on my laptop, I'll try it on my work computer in a while, and then I will just confirm it with you. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: @LukasLang Just an update, works perfectly on work computer as well!

Comment: Hey @LukasLang I tried opening the documentation page of my paclet, NotebookOpen["paclet:workcodes/ReferencePages/Symbols/workcodes"] but it outputted with "$Failed" . How do I open the documentation page?

Comment: @blacke23 I have put all my comments into an answer, including info on how to find the documentation - feel free to ask for clarifications!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<sub>*Putting my comment into an answer, since it seems to have solved the question*</sub>

You can use [`ResourceFunction["PacletizeResourceFunction"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PacletizeResourceFunction) to package a collection of resource functions into a paclet, which can then be installed on another computer.

The process works like this:
Let's say you want the resource functions [`LensManipulate`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/LensManipulate/) and [`AncientNumberRepresentation`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AncientNumberRepresentation/) on a computer without internet.

1. Create the paclet on the computer with internet:

   ```
   ResourceFunction["PacletizeResourceFunction"][
     {
       "LensManipulate",
       "AncientNumberRepresentation"
     },
     "useful.paclet",
     "PacletName"->"MyPaclet"
   ]
   (* "C:\\Users\\lukas\\Documents\\useful.paclet" *)
   ```
2. Copy the file to your other computer
3. Install the paclet:

   ```
   PacletInstall["C:\\Users\\lukas\\Documents\\useful.paclet"]
   ```

   [image]
4. Use the functions as you would otherwise (note that the function is not wrapped in `ResourceFunction[...]`):

   ```
   AncientNumberRepresentation[13, "Babylonian"]
   ```

   [image]
5. To look at the documentation, use the same methods as for normal functions:

   - With the cursor in the function name, press `F1` (or whatever the shortcut is on your system)
   - Use the info popup button
   - Use the search in the documentation center
   - Navigate to it via the paclet guide page (see next point)

   [image]
6. You can manage the paclet & go to the main overview page via the documentation center: Go to the home page, and scroll to the very bottom. Click on the "Add-ons and packages" link, and you should see an overview of the installed paclets:
   [image]
   The overview guide page looks like this (reached by clicking the "Documentation" button or the paclet name):
   [image]
   You can also reach the paclet overview page by searching the documentation for the name of the paclet:
   [image]
7. In the latest version of `PacletizeResourceFunction` (this is not yet accepted to the function repository, for now it can be accessed via `ResourceFunction[CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/langl/DeployedResources/Function/PacletizeResourceFunction"]]`), it is also possible to update an existing paclet with new/updated functions without having to reprocess all the existing ones. The workflow would go something like this:

   ```
   PacletizeResourceFunction=
    ResourceFunction[CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/langl/DeployedResources/Function/PacletizeResourceFunction"]];

   (* create a first version of the paclet *)
   PacletizeResourceFunction[{"AreaBetweenCurves"}, "CodeFinal.paclet", "PacletName" -> "Codes"]
   (* "D:\\lukas\\Documents\\CodeFinal.paclet" *)

   (* install the paclet file, possibly on another computer *)
   PacletInstall@"CodeFinal.paclet"
   (* PacletObject["Codes"] *)

   (* load the paclet *)
   << Codes`

   (* it contains the following functions: *)
   Names["Codes`*"]
   (* {"AreaBetweenCurves"} *)
   ```

   To update the paclet, run the command again, but with a different list of functions. Make sure that the old paclet file is at the target location of the command. This way, `PacletizeResourceFunction` will see the paclet file and update it, rather than generating a new one from scatch

   ```
   PacletizeResourceFunction[{"ColorSearch"}, "CodeFinal.paclet",  "PacletName" -> "Codes"]
   (* "D:\\lukas\\Documents\\CodeFinal.paclet" *)

   (* again on the other computer, uninstall the old version (this might need a restart of Mathematica to complete fully) *)
   PacletUninstall@"Codes"

   (* install the new version *)
   PacletInstall@"CodeFinal.paclet"
   (* PacletObject["Codes"] *)

   (* load it *)
   << Codes`

   (* now, both functions are available from the paclet: *)
   Names["Codes`*"]
   (* {"AreaBetweenCurves", "ColorSearch"} *)
   ```

Comment: This is really nice - local documentation is a great bonus on top of all of this. It makes me wonder if you could just download all of the resource functions to a paclet and sync them every once in a while...

Comment: @CarlLange you'd probably need to be *very* patient if you tried that :) (the notebook-manipulation tasks used for the documentation-extraction are unfortunately super slow)

Comment: @LukasLang Hey, can you add more functions to a paclet once you have made it? Or do you have to make a new one each time you wish to add more functions onto it?

Comment: @blacke23 Sorry for the delayed reply - I thought I could "quickly" implement something, but as it goes, it took a lot longer than expected... Anyway: In the current version, you'll have to regenerate the full paclet each time, yes. However, I have just submitted an updated version that includes the ability to add functions to an existing paclet without having to reprocess the rest. Until it is submitted, you can access it as `ResourceFunction[
CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/langl/DeployedResources/Function/PacletizeResourceFunction"]]`. If you find any issues, let me know!

Comment: @LukasLang Im a bit confused, so I copied the command into my notebook and it came with the with square brackets and a circle in the middle, with "PacletResourceFunction" eg. something like this [*]PacletResourceFunction I'm lost as to what to do from here onwards. thanks

Comment: @blacke23 sorry, I should have been more clear: that is a replacement for `ResourceFunction["PacletizeResourceFunction"]` (essentially, you're telling Mathematica where exactly to get the resource functions from, whereas the default way just tells it to look for a function with the specified name in the default repository). To make it easier, you can copy the output of that command and use it instead of `ResourceFunction["PacletizeResourceFunction"]`. Alternatively, you can save the output to a variable and use that instead. So e.g. `prf=ResourceFunction[…]` and then `prf[{"function1,",…}]`

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks for that, If I understood correctly, I did `ResourceFunction[
  CloudObject[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/langl/DeployedResources/Function/\
PacletizeResourceFunction"]][{"AreaBetweenCurves"}, \
"CodeFinal.paclet", "PacletName" -> "codes"]` , where 'codes' was my original paclet.  However when I installed it again, it only contained the new function and not the other. I think  I have misinterpreted how to do it.

Comment: @blacke23 No, I think you did everything correctly. The issue is that the updating only works for paclets generated with the updated version of `PacletizeResourceFunction` (this is because additional information is required for the update process, and this information is only included since the latest version of `PacletizeResourceFunction`). So if you try again to update the newly created paclet, it should work. If not, please let me know

Comment: @LukasLang Hey sorry for the late reply. So I tried it and now it came with ```JLink`KeepJavaObject::obj: At least one argument to KeepJavaObject was not a valid Java object.```

Comment: @LukasLang I again did as the following ```ResourceFunction[
  CloudObject[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/langl/DeployedResources/Function/\
PacletizeResourceFunction"]][{"AreaBetweenCurves"}, \
"CodeFinal.paclet", "PacletName" -> "codes"]```

Comment: @blacke23 hmm... Something seems to be broken in the online version. I'll try to fix it and will let you know once I found a solution

Comment: @blacke23 Can you try again now? I have updated the function to fix the issue I was talking about and for me, your command now seems to work as expected.

Comment: @LukasLang Hey lukas, sorry i was a bit busy. Umm so I tried ```ResourceFunction[
  CloudObject[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/langl/DeployedResources/Function/\
\ PacletizeResourceFunction"]][{"AreaBetweenCurves"}, \
"CodeFinal.packlet", "PacletName" -> "Codes"]``` again, but this time I got ```CloudObject::cloudnf: No CloudObject found at the given address``` and " $Failed[{"AreaBetweenCurves"}, "CodeFinal.packlet", 
 "PacletName" -> "codes"] "

Comment: @blacke23 Hmm... Can you try with the following command? `ResourceFunction[ CloudObject[ "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/langl/DeployedResources/Function/PacletizeResourceFunction"]][{"AreaBetweenCurves"}, "CodeFinal.packlet", "PacletName" -> "Codes"]` (it looks like something added some spurious `\ ` to the URL in your commamd)

Comment: @LukasLang That worked, and it did all the work such as indexing, but then I restarted Mathematica, but the new function wasn't added to the packlet (when i searched up by pressing f1)

Comment: @blacke23 Did you install the resulting paclet file successfully using `PacletInstall`? If yes, does the paclet show up in the "Add-ons and Packages" section, or when using `PacletFind["Codes"]`?

Comment: @LukasLang Do I have to first uninstall the old paclet and then reinstall the new on?

Comment: @blacke23 Depends - In principle, updated paclets should have a higher version number, and you should be able to just install them (otherwise, Mathematica will produce an error message). But uninstalling the old one should never hurt, even if it's not strictly required.

Comment: @LukasLang Hey, so I realised once I added a new function to the paclet, it creates a new file that contains the same name. Now the problem arrives when i have to install it again, i don't know which onethe new one is? if that makes sense

Comment: @LukasLang Hey I managed to find the new file, however only the new function was in it, and the rest weren't...

Comment: @blacke23 That is really strange... I have update the answer with a step-by-step guide on how to update an existing paclet (Point 7 in the list). Can you give that a go and see whether it works for you?

Comment: @LukasLang Yep that works. Thank you once again for your help. Legend!

Answer (score 1):

Just quickly some ideas that work with `v14` or earlier. I note that upon calling `ResourceFunction[<resfunc>]` that function seems to be stored as a local object in `$LocalBase` and you can check this with `LocalObjects[]`. Below is a more controlled approach.

#### Embedding cached resource functions within a paclet

While Lukas’ solution is very nice, I often find myself wanting to embedd certain resource functions within some paclet, e.g., some utilities I am using on a day to day basis.

For this purpose, I am currently using the following approach, which I will demonstrate for the resource function [`DatasetForm`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/DatasetForm/?i=DatasetForm&searchapi=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.wolframcloud.com%2FFunctionRepository%2Fsearch):

1. Set `$LocalBase = <path to PacletMainDirectory/ResourceFunctions/>`.
2. Cache a resource function there using `LocalCache[ ResourceFunction[“DatasetForm”]]`.
3. Register the directory name for the cached resource function as an `”Asset”` in the `PacletObject` in `PacletInfo.wl`. The following is an example as the directory name will, of course, differ:

```
“Extensions” -> {
    … ,
   {   "Asset",
       "Root" -> "ResourceFunctions",
       "Assets" -> {
           { "DatasetForm", "6694cdf9-f621-4bd4-926f8e7a5384592e/" },
            …
       }
   }
}
```

4. In the public context of your paclet do:

```
DatasetForm::usage = ResourceFunction[
    PacletObject[“<pacletname>”][“AssetLocation”, “DatasetForm”], “Usage”
]
```

5. In the private context of your paclet do:

```
DatasetForm = ResourceFunction[
    PacletObject[“<pacletname”][“AssetLocation”, “DatasetForm”], “Function”]
]
```

6. Repeat steps 2-5 for other resource functions if needed. Do not forget to reset `$LocalBase = $DefaultLocalBase` (haven’t checked whether a simple `$LocalBase =.` will also work).

You are all set and the paclet can now provide the resource function as an embedded local object via your paclet server.