# ResourceFunction is stuck at "Finding Resource"

Tags: paclets, resourcefunction

[image]

It was working perhaps until a week ago. Now it gets stuck on similar invocations with no apparent activity. The only way out is a kernel restart.  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> does not work.

1. I am using v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.
2. Previously downloaded resource functions are still usable.
3. Entity system is functional.

What could be wrong and how can this be fixed? When using a resource function that has not been downloaded yet, does the software download other unrequested but mandatory paclets etc? Could it be holding up the process?

**EDIT2**

While trying (among) other things such as `TestInternetConnectivity` from the `Preferences`, the following error shows up:

[image]

> URLFetch::ssl : An SSL error occurred . The raw details are :
> "libcurl error (35): schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext 
> failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually 
> occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake 
> failed). "

Google search reveals that many users have recently been getting the same error message while using other programs. Perhaps it is a browser setup issue or the server implementing more security protocols now for which my windows machine is not set up.

---

Thanks for your help.

Comment: FWIW, it works on 13.1 on Mac OS Big Sur.

Comment: Works on MMA 13.1 Windows 10

Comment: Thank you both. As I mentioned, it was working on v12.2.0 a week ago. I am thinking that some file or directory got corrupted and I am looking for a standard procedure/workaround to reset this functionality etc.

Comment: I've got the same problem and afraid that real problem is in Windows 7. On 10 all work. But I like my notebook with Win 7 so hope someone can help

Comment: Maybe download the source notebook (from the button at the top right) and install it as a package manually. I had trouble with the resource function AntiSimplify (although i believe a different one) and did that if I remember well.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm afraid that the problem is in Win 7. But I would like to continue using this OS on one of the laptops.
Therefore, I found a working solution - download all the necessary functions on the device where it's possible, and create a local paclet, as [described here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246751/how-to-download-resourcefunction-packages-onto-a-notebook-so-i-can-place-it-i).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will look at this further. I have been downloading and using these, but this pacletizaton would improve the procedure  and make it more convenient.

Comment: May I ask if you have been able to isolate the problem and why it started less than a month ago?