# Fit a point that defines a 90° angle

Tags: fitting, linear-algebra, geometry

I'm trying to come up with a fit that will give me x,y coordinates of a point, that best fit in 2 slopes, the 2 slopes intercepting at 90°.

At the moment I fit individually 2 lines to a 2 sets of measured points.

```
topline = LinearModelFit[{{666.638, 769.106}, {530.36, 566.72}, {499.235, 519.357}, {530.6, 
  567.42}}, x, x];
botline = LinearModelFit[{{791.76, 123.04}, {591.025, 259.925}, {545.76, 292.54}, {586.919, 
  263.629}}, x, x];
{x0 = x /. Solve[Normal[topline] == Normal[botline], x][[ 1]],
  z0 = Normal[botline[x0]]}
```

This trivially gives `x0 and y0 = 409.01, 385.807` but does not forces the 2 lines to be perpendicular. Because of the measurement errors in the set of coordinates, I routinely end with values in the 89-91° range. However it has to be 90°, because it physically set up that way. I would like to find a fit function that will come up with the best `x0,y0` obeying a right angle of the 2 slopes.

I tried using Solve, itself containing the 2 above LinearModelFit with an additional variable point, but this does not work, as LinearModelFit won't work with undefined points.

Comment: I suggest that you think about what your errors are.  Least squares fitting (e.g. `y=a x + c`) assumes that you have errors in your `y` values, but not your `x` values.  If you might have solutions close to `y=c`, then this model seems questionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand you try to find two perpendicular lines fitting your data:

That means first set of data is fitted by `a1+m1 x` and second set is fitted by `a2-1/m1 x`!

```
ptop = {{666.638, 769.106}, {530.36, 566.72}, {499.235,519.357}, {530.6,567.42}};
pbot = {{791.76, 123.04}, {591.025, 259.925}, {545.76,292.54}, {586.919,263.629}};

mini = NMinimize[
{Total[Map[(#[[2]] - (a1 + m1 #[[1]]))^2 &, ptop]] + 
Total[Map[(#[[2]] - (a2 - 1/m1 #[[1]]))^2 &, pbot]], m1 > 0}, {a1,a2, m1}]
(* {8.01103, {a1 -> -217.216, a2 -> 660.241, m1 -> 1.47809}}*)
```

intersection point

```
solx = Solve[a1 + m1 x == a2 - 1/m1 x  , x][[1]]
pt = {x, a1 + m1 x} /. solx /. mini[[2]] (*{407.241, 384.724}*)
```

result

```
Show[{ListPlot[{ptop, pbot}], 
Plot[Evaluate[{a1 + m1 x, a2 - 1/m1 x} /. mini[[2]]], {x, 100,800}],   
Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large],Point[pt]}]}, AspectRatio -> 1 ,PlotRange -> {{ 0, 1000}, {0, 1000}}]
```

[image]

**remark**

I know the resourcefunction `ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"]`
which is able to handle two datasets but I failed trying `ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][{ptop, pbot}, {a1 + m1 x,  a2 - 1/m1 x}, {a1, a2, m1}, x]`

**addendum**

An easy solution using `Region`-functionality

define a cross-region

```
reg = RegionUnion[InfiniteLine[{x0, y0}, {Cos[alfa], Sin[alfa]}], 
InfiniteLine[{x0, y0}, {Cos[alfa + 90 \[Degree]],Sin[alfa + 90 \[Degree]]}]]

mini = FindMinimum[Total@Map[RegionDistance[reg , #]^2 &, Join[ptop, pbot]], 
{{x0, 400}, {y0, 500}, {alfa, 5 \[Degree]}}] // Quiet
(*{4.0295, {x0 -> 407.106, y0 -> 385.437, alfa -> 0.974064}}*)
```

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Any idea what's wrong with my attempt `ResourceFunction["MultiNonlinearModelFit"][{ptop, pbot}, {a1 + m1 x,  a2 - 1/m1 x}, {a1, a2, m1}, x]`? Mathematica v12.2  displays "Finding Resource..."  but doesn't evaluate. Thanks!

Comment: I have a [similar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276726/resourcefunction-is-stuck-at-finding-resource) problem with v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: Works in version 14

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks for your reply! Hope it gives the same result

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann  Yes it does.

Comment: That works great, thanks.

Comment: @Apostdoc For your interest,  I added a solution which uses Mathematica's `Region`-functionality. See my answer.