# Error while running the ResourceFunction

Tags: resourcefunction

I am trying to use a resource function, but when I execute

```
ResourceFunction["NestedLookup"]
```

I get back `$Failed`.
I cannot figure out what is wrong.

I am running Mathematica 13.2.1, on MacOS 13.6.4.

Comment: This is only slightly different from the unresolved [276726](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276726/resourcefunction-is-stuck-at-finding-resource). Can you please include OS information as well?

Comment: Works well for me in 14.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: Included the OS information above. It is a similar issue, but it is not the same I think.

Comment: Works on my MBP (Sonoma 14.3) with MMA version "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)"